# Set headers before request in Rails Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

In Ruby on Rails Minitest, is there any way to set the headers before calling the request, within an `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` test?

Inside the `before`/`setup` is not a solution at the moment.

```
# Default way
test 'foo' do
  get '/home', headers: { foo: "bar" }
end

# How I wish
test 'foo' do
  @request.headers['foo'] = "bar"

  get '/home'
end

# I already tried and it did not work...
test 'foo' do
  request.headers['foo'] = 'bar'
  @request.headers['foo'] = 'bar'
  request.env['foo'] = 'bar'
  @request.env['foo'] = 'bar'
  request.env['HTTP_FOO'] = 'bar'
  @request.env['HTTP_FOO'] = 'bar'

  get '/home'
end
```

---

- Ruby version: ruby 2.5.1p57
- Rails version: 5.2.0
- Minitest version: 5.1

Answer (score 3):

The default way is good, but according to naming of headers custom header you should start with "X-" prefix.

```
test 'foo' do
  get '/home', headers: { "X-Foo": "bar" }
end
```

Comment: Well remembered, I'm using the prefix, "foo" and "bar" were just examples. And the default way is not what I'm looking for.